# Trying to print entire dataframe after str.replace on one column

Tags: pandas

I can't figure out why this is throwing the error:
`KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")`

here is the code:

```
def get_company_name(df):
    company_name = [col for col in df if col.lower().startswith('comp')]
    return company_name
df = df[df[get_company_name(master_leads)[0]].str.replace(punc, '', regex=True)]
```

this is what df.head() looks like:

```
                                  Company / Account                       Website
0  Big Moose RV, & Boat Sales, Service, Camper Re...  https://bigmooservsales.com/
1           Holifield Pest Management of Hattiesburg                           NaN
2                            Steve Nichols Insurance                           NaN
3                                    Sandel Law Firm                 sandellaw.com
4    Duplicate - Checkered Flag FIAT of Newport News                           NaN
```

I have tried putting the `[]` in every place possible but I must be missing something. I was under impression that this is how you ran transformations on one column of the dataframe without pulling the series out of the dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Ian, I am trying to remove all punctuation from each row of the column company name then save the entire dataframe with the newly cleaned company name column inside the otherwise original dataframe. I just realized I didn’t include the punc variable. It is a regex to remove punctuation as I’m sure you probably guessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first column name for company with

```
company_name_col = [col for col in df if col.lower().startswith('comp')][0]
```

you can see the cleaned up company name with

```
df[company_name_col].str.replace(punc, "", regex=True)
```

to apply the replacement

```
df[company_name_col] = df[company_name_col].str.replace(punc, "", regex=True)
```

Comment: Thank you Ian! This is great!